# AlertDialog.Builder dissapears even when no button is clicked and setcancelable is false

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

so im using an alert dialog and it doesnt even last for 5 seconds without instantly dissapearing evethough i wouldnt have clicked anything can anyone help?

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

    deleteCopy();

   info.setText("\n\n***\n"
            + "Alarm is set @ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
            + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
 Intent alarmIIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent intent_ForResult = new Intent(TimeDateRem.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent_ForResult);}

    public void deleteCopy() {
    Cursor cursor = dba.getnameofAlarm(title.getText().toString());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            final DatabaseActivity dba= new DatabaseActivity(getApplicationContext());
            String titleData=(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_NAME)));

            if(title.getText().toString().matches(titleData)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TimeDateRem.this);

                builder.setTitle("Set Alarm");

                builder.setMessage("By setting this alarm you will be deleting the previous one, is that OK?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                dba.deleteAlarm(title.getText().toString().trim());
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }


        cursor.close();
    }
```

deletecopy() deletes any row from database that has the same name of the currently created one... any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are calling `setAlarm` and it creates a `Dialog` (in `deleteCopy`) and then later starts `MainActivity`. Dialogs are hosted by activities and when you switch the activity the dialog goes away. Try starting the activity on the OK click of the dialog.

Comment: isnt the dialog supposed to stay until i click one of the buttons? i did setcancelable to false for that reason..i dont want the code to keep running.. and i cant start activity in there since i need the intent @FranciscoM.

Comment: No, dialogs show and the execution continues, it does not block on `deleteCopy();` or `alertDialog.show();`. Otherwise the user interface would freeze. Dialog will stay there and will execute the `OnClickListener` code asynchronously, when the click happens.

Comment: setcancelable is about not letting the user leave the dialog, not about blocking execution of the UI thread. Ui thread should never be blocked because it is responsable for refreshing views on screen.

Comment: what can i do to keep the alertdialog then...is there a way to stall until i click a button ? @FranciscoM.

Comment: yes you put you code on the onClickListener and start the activity there, or whatever you need to do that happens after the click

Comment: You never want to stall ui thread code execution. If you have something that will need to stall you allways must create another thread of execution and then comunicate to the ui thread your results, for example. the ui thread is like the bus in movie Speed.

Comment: but look at my code...adding startActivity inside it will ruin my code so its just not possible... and nice example @FranciscoM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this works but its like i said in the comments, you must move your after click logic to the onClickListener

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
    deleteCopyAsk(targetCal);
}

public void deleteCopyAsk(final Calendar targetCal) {
    Cursor cursor = dba.getnameofAlarm(title.getText().toString());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final DatabaseActivity dba = new DatabaseActivity(getApplicationContext());
        String titleData = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_NAME)));
        if (title.getText().toString().matches(titleData)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TimeDateRem.this);
            builder.setTitle("Set Alarm");
            builder.setMessage("By setting this alarm you will be deleting the previous one, is that OK?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dba.deleteAlarm(title.getText().toString().trim());

                            info.setText("\n\n***\n"
                                    + "Alarm is set @ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                                    + "***\n");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
                            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                            Intent alarmIIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                            Intent intent_ForResult = new Intent(TimeDateRem.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent_ForResult);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```